# DocumentRoot and VSCode intelephense

Tags: visual-studio-code, document-root

How can I set the Workspace in Visual Studio Code so that the "intelephense" mechanism will suggest me the autocompletion for paths starting from the directory that I use as DocumentRoot (Apache), instead of starting from the VS Code Workspace Directory?

e.g.
My project (workspace) directory is called 'website'; it contains the 'public' directory, which contains index.html and style.css . If, in the html file, I start typing `href="./`, where I want to link the file with the style, intelephense suggests `public`, which would be wrong!

What I actually want is:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">`

since the file with the style is in the same directory of the html file that is linking to it.

So it would be correct if intelephense would suggest me `style.css`, when I start typying: `href="./`, instead of suggesting: `public`.

I have tried this code inside the VS Code workspace file:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "intelephense.environment.documentRoot": "./public"
    }
}
```

but that doesn't do the trick - I am not even sure this is the way to go.